# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar un objeto de una lista en Java basándome en un objeto de otra clase?

Tags: java

Por dar un ejemplo, tengo una lista de objetos de la clase Queso en Java. Supongamos que cada objeto Queso de esa lista, tiene una referencia de un objeto de otra clase en su interior, es decir, dentro de la clase Queso hay una variable de un objeto de otra clase, supongamos por ejemplo  que ese objeto representa una comida que lleva queso, entonces dentro de la clase Queso, puede haber un objeto de clase Pizza o de la clase Tarta,etc; Entonces mi pregunta es, si hay alguna forma de que al usar el metodo remove de la lista de la Clase queso, y pasandole el objeto que tiene por referencia esa clase, y no el objeto queso en si, puedo hacer que se elimine ese objeto Queso, es decir listaQuesos.remove(objetoPizza), entonces el objeto Queso especifico, que contenga el objetoPizza sera eliminado de la lista, puede hacerse algo asi? ¿Como? Tengo entendido que algo asi se puede hacer modificando el metodo equals de esas clases, pero sin embargo, probando no he logrado dar como hacerlo.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código que has intentado y cuál es el problema o error? Pulsa en [edit] para completar tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, tienes una colección de Objetos. Has de saber que en principio todos los objetos de una lista tienen que ser del mismo tipo. Según indicas en tu código la clase principal es la clase queso, pero luego quieres que pizza o tarta pertenezcan a la clase queso. Por lo pronto yo haría lo siguiente:

```
public class Comida //Declaramos Comida como la clase base de la jerarquía
```

Y a partir de ahora hacemos una clase para cada respectiva comida:

```
public class Queso extends Comida...
public class Piza extends Comida...
public class Tarta extends Comida...
```

A partir de este punto nuestro programa cuenta con una estructura jerárquica que resulta concisa e intuitiva. Bien, ahora llega el momento de agrupar varios de estos objetos dentro de una misma colección. Desconozco cuál has utilizado en tu código porque no lo clarificas en tu pregunta, pero yo te propondría usar un `ArrayList`. Java es un lenguaje de programación fuertemente tipado, por lo que como dijimos antes, todo lo que metas dentro de una lista tiene que ser del mismo tipo. (Puede haber excepciones si tenemos en cuenta que todo objeto en Java hereda de la clase Object, por lo que creando una lista de tipo Object, podríamos meter cualquier cosa dentro, pero eso para otro momento). Con todo, yo haría lo siguiente:

```
ArrayList<Comida>listaComidas=new ArrayList<>();
```

Pongamos que tienes un objeto Queso q1 y un objeto Piza p1, podemos añadirlos a la lista de la siguiente manera:

```
listaComidas.add(q1);
listaComidas.add(p1);
```

Y puesto que tanto `q1` como `p1` son Objetos de tipo Comida, no habría ningún problema en este punto.

Veamos ahora como eliminar un objeto determinado que tengamos contenido en nuestra lista `listaComidas`. Puedes emplear `remove` de varias maneras:

- `remove(int index)` : elimina el elemento de esa posición determinada de la lista
- `remove(Object o)`:elimina la primera ocurrencia de un objeto dentro de la lista, siempre y cuando el objeto esté contenido dentro de dicha lista.

Probablemente la más útil para nuestro caso sea la segunda. Veamos que aspecto tendría nuestra lista `listaComidas` después de llevar a cabo la eliminación del Objeto de tipo Piza `p1`:

```
listaComidas.remove(p1);

//en este punto listaComidas solamente contendría al objeto de tipo queso q1
```

Recuerda que puedes consultar el [API de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) siempre que lo necesites.